# Hide weekdays and specific dates of jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a function that hides the days of the weeks datepicker. Need, in addition to this, hide specific days ... 
Ex: "09/09/2014", "10/10/2014"

This is my jquery ...

```
jQuery("#wpsc_checkout_form_9998").datepicker( 
            "option", 
            "beforeShowDay", 
            function(date) { 
                var day = date.getDay();
                return [(day != 4) && (day != 2), ''];
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of the days you want to exclude and add checking for them in the `beforeShowDay` option:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var arrDisabledDates = {};
  arrDisabledDates[new Date('08/08/2014')] = new Date('08/08/2014');
  arrDisabledDates[new Date('08/30/2014')] = new Date('08/30/2014');

   $('#txtDate').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        var day = date.getDay(),
                            bDisable = arrDisabledDates[date];
                         if (bDisable) return [false, '', '']
                         else return [(day != 4) && (day != 2)];
      }
   });
});
```

Find Demo here: [jQuery Datepicker excluding specific dates and days](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/VQdbx/37/)

This is an adjusted version of an example for excluding specific dates I just found here: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/03/hide-disable-dates-in-jquery-ui-datepicker.html