# how to disable specific days in JQuery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to disable all the Sunday,Monday and Wednesday from my jquery date-picker. I am trying to do this using the following code sample -

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".datepicker").datepicker({
          beforeShowDay: function(date) {
              var day = date.getDay();
              return [(day != 1), ''];
          }
      })
  });
```

This code disable all Mondays from the calender. How can i disable all Sunday and Wednesdays too?

Comment: see [this](http://webtricksandtreats.com/disable-specific-days-jquery-ui-date-picker/), it may help  you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344382/hide-weekdays-and-specific-dates-of-jaquery-datepicker

Comment: Just like you did `(day!=1)` - `(day != 1 && day != 3 && day != 0)`. 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday ..and so on.

Comment: i have dynamic days to disable. but i have mentioned 2 days as treatment for multiple days may b similar .

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 0), ''];
    }
});
```

Comment: for weekends you can try like this..$(function() {
   $('#txtDate1').datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
   });
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({

 beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 3 && day != 0), ''];
    }
});
```

The days of week go as 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday and so on.

So `day != DayNumber` will solve it for you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Fy9/977/)